# How can I remove a gap between my Column children?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter screen that is built with the code below. I expected the ListView widget and the Row widget to have no space between them. But the code produces the results shown in the screen capture instead. How do I get rid of the gap between the two widgets?

```
  Material(
    color: const Color.fromARGB(128, 0, 0, 0),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 56.0, right: 150.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                  child: Text('Select a new grocery list:'),
                ), // Padding
              ],
            ), // Row
          ), // Container
          ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                      ), // Border
                    ), //BoxDecoration
                    child: ListTile(
                      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                      title: Text(groceryListNames[index]),
                      textColor: Constants.kDarkBlueTextColor,
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, groceryListNames[index]);
                      },
                    ), // ListTile
                  ); // Container
                },
                itemCount: groceryListNames.length),
        ],
      ), // Column
    ), // Padding
  ), // Material
```

[image: Screen Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` to your `ListView.builder()` to remove unwanted paddings:

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
);
```

Or

Use `ListView.builder()` as the child of `MediaQuery.removePadding` to remove any top padding applied by the device or system:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: ListView.builder(),
);
```

Comment: The first solution did exactly what I wanted.